# Should I install JMS broker on a separate machine?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jms

I am using Spring Boot mail and a JMS broker to build an email system. I followed [this example project](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-jms/). Because our application QPS is small one server is enough to handle the requests. In the example project the broker, sender, and receiver are all on the same server. Is this a good practice for small application? Or I should put the broker, sender, and receiver on three separate machines?

Comment: The way this question is worded the answers will be based on opinion, not fact. This question should either be changed or closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's depends...

The size of the application is irrelevant. It depends more on your requirements for availability, scalability and data safety.

If you have everything on the same machine you have a single point of risk. If the machine crash you lost everything on that machine. But this setup is the most 
simple one (also for maintenance) and the change that the server will crash is low. Modern machines are able to handle a big load.

If you have a really high load and/or a requirement for guaranteed delivery you should use multiple systems with producers that sends messages to an ActiveMQ cluster (also distributed over multiple machines). The consumers, also on more than one machine. Use also load balancers to connect/interface to the machines.

You can also have a setup in the middle of both example setups (simple and 
 complex).

If you are able to reproduce all the messages (email messages in your example), and the load is not so high, I will advise you to put it simple all on the same machine.

Comment: The flip-side of the "single point of failure" argument is that if you put different functions on different machines, then each machine is now a potential point of failure.  (Just saying.)

Comment: yes, that's true. And on 1 single machine you don't have problems with network, ports and firewall problems. Security is also simpler.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is it depends. The longn answer is measure it. The use of small application criteria is flawed. You can have both on the same server if your server have all the resources required by your application and message queue broker, and not impacting the performance of end user.

I would suggest run your performance tests to test your criteria then decide your target environment setup.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest setup is everything on the same box. If this one box has enough CPU and disk space, why not ? One (performance) advantage is that nothing needs to go over the network.

If you are concerned about fault-tolerance, replicate that whole setup on a second machine.